# textbox dropdown after a seletec

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textbox

i just wanted to ask how to auto dropdown the textbox based on the number selected.
For example, i have a dropdown values of 2,3,4,5,etc, when I click the 2, it would dropdown two textboxes, three if the value is 3, thank you, very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it. Show us some code.

Comment: I dont really have the code, I was just researching on the topic and later asked here. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "drop down a text box"?

Comment: add a textbox based on the values 1,2,3, if I select 1, it would add one textbox. sorry

Comment: Thanks david, but its not what i mean, i mean for example, i have a dropdown menu, values of 1,2,3 and so on. What I want is when I click 3, it would show 3 textboxes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST["value"])){
        $num = $_REQUEST["value"];
        for($loop =1; $loop <=$num; $loop++){
            ?>
                <div>TextBox <?php echo $loop;?><input type = 'text' name = "input_box_<?php echo "$loop ";?> ">
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
<form method = "post">
Select Number
 <select name = "value">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>

</select>
<input type ="Submit" />
```

Comment: this i what i mean, thanks mubin khalid, :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to auto-hide/auto-show a text `input` based on the value of a `select` element?  Something like this should work:

```
<select id="theSelect">
    <option value="0">Select an option...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="theText" style="display:none;" />
```

And then in your jQuery code:

```
$('#theSelect').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '1') {
        $('#theText').show();
    } else {
        $('#theText').hide();
    }
});
```

You can use different animations for the show/hide part, of course.  But the basic idea is that you are hiding it by default (for which I used inline CSS in this example, but you can just as easily use your existing CSS file) and then show/hide it based on some condition when the `select` value changes.